# A question about $x^p\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^q} \right )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let's define $f(x) = x^p\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^q} \right)$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Here, $p$ and $q$ are positive real numbers.

Could anyone explain to me what are the conditions of $p,q$ to make $f(x)$ absolutely continuous or bounded variation? I'm just stuck..